# Update ChildComponent Property using ViewChild

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, viewchild

I am pretty new Angular and I am playing around with ViewChild and ViewChildren. I tried a scenario where
I have a `today = new Date()` property in my `Component2`. And I am accessing this property in my `Component1` using `ViewChild` and updating the time using `setInterval() for every second`.

Now I created the multiple Component2 's using `*ngFor` directive. But I see that only the initial Component2 's `today` property is being updated. Remaining are not being updated.

Below is my code.

Component1.ts

```
import{Component,ViewChild,ElementRef,AfterViewInit,OnInit,ViewChildren,QueryList}from"@angular/core";

import { Component2 } from "./Component2";

@Component({
  selector: "comp1",
  templateUrl: "./Component1.html"
})
export class Component1 implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(Component2) myComponent2: Component2;

  public Component2Array: Array<String> = [
    "Paragraph one",
    "Paragraph Two",
    "Paragraph Three",
    "Paragraph Four"
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log("Component 1 => AfterViewInit", this.myComponent2);
    setInterval(()=>
    {
      this.myComponent2.today = new Date();
    }) 
  }
}
```

Component1.html

```
<div #div1>
  <h1 #header1>This is Header 1</h1>
</div>
<div #component2Div>
  <comp2 *ngFor="let item of Component2Array" [message]="item"> </comp2>
</div>
```

Component2.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  Input
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "comp2",
  templateUrl: "./Component2.html"
})
export class Component2 implements AfterViewInit {
  public today = new Date();
  
  @Input() message: string;
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {}
}
```

Component2.html

```
<div>
  <h1>This is Component 2</h1>
  <h2>{{today}}</h2>
  <div>
    {{message}}
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please let me know why only the initial Component2's `today` property is updating.
[Example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-buck-qv15l?file=/src/app/Components/Component2.html:0-113)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue myself. I was using `ViewChild` instead of `ViewChildren`.
Changed the code from

```
@ViewChild(Component2) myComponent2: Component2;
```

to

```
@ViewChildren(Component2) myComponent2: QueryList<Component2>;
```

and

from

```
setInterval(()=>
{
  this.myComponent2.today = new Date();
})
```

to

```
setInterval(() => {
      this.components.forEach((element) => (element.today = new Date()));
    });
```